# How To Get the Correct Character length of the Category Archives Page Title

Tags: archive-template

I am trying to get the character length of a category archive page. I know i can use

```
$page_title_length = strlen(get_the_archive_title() );
```

However, for some reason, this gives a higher number than expected. For example, if I go to the archive page of post category 'uncategorized', the result i get for the string "Category: Uncategorized" is '36', while it should be '24'! I tried everything, but to no avail.

Here is my whole code:

```
/**
 * Get Page title letters length
 */

function prefix_get_page_title_length() {
    $page_title_length = '';
    if (is_archive() ){
        $page_title_length = strlen( get_the_archive_title() );
    }
    
    else {
        // Everything else
        $page_title_length = strlen( get_the_title() );
    }
    var_dump(get_the_archive_title() ); // Returns "Category: Uncategorized string(36) "
    return $page_title_length;
}
```

The code works on single pages (it gets the correct number of letters but it returns more letters for some reason for the category archives. Please help.

UPDATE: It seems that `get_the_archive_title()` adds up additional string with the string info at the end but I have no idea why and how to remove it?

Comment: `strlen()` counts _bytes_, not characters. Use [`mb_strlen( $string, 'utf-8' )`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) if you need the actual character length.

Comment: I just tried it, but it also returns '36' instead of '24'. When i try to dump the `get_the_archive_title()`, i get as a result "Category: Uncategorized string(36) ". I suspect this is where the problem comes from, but why does "string(36)" also gets counted?

Comment: when you view the category archive page, what is the title you see? Is it correct on the web page?

Comment: Yes, it returns: Category: Uncategorized

Comment: Wow, i found out what the problem is (though I still do not fully understand it). I should use `wp_kses( get_the_archive_title(), array() )`  instead of just  `get_the_archive_title()` ! Now it is working. Thanks everyone!